# Redirect all to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect all http and https to 1 domain, thus I'd be interested to know the code to add into the `.htaccess` file in order to redirect:

From: `HTTP(non-www) + HTTP(www) + HTTPS(www)` To: `HTTPS(non-www)`

I have found the following answer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https:// %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

but it redirects to `HTTPS(www)` for as far I understood and mine should be redirected to `HTTPS(non-www)`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you always redirect to a specific domain which is always the same, then you just need to put it instead of `%{HTTP_HOST}` in your `RewriteRule`.
The `%{HTTP_HOST}` tells to use the same http hostname as the source of the redirect. But you need to have your own destination name, not copied from the source.

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) https://mydomain.com/%{REQUEST_URI}
```

P.S.: Please make sure the destination domain does not have the same rule to avoid cyclic redirects.

Comment: Well I added it and it turned out it now has a redirect loop.. What do I do now?

Comment: That's why I suggested to check that destination did not have redirect rule so it won't loop. You need to make sure the Rewrite rule does not apply/exist there.

Comment: I'm quite new to this.. so that won't happen again. I added it in the SEO Yoast Wordpress HTAccess file but if I download the htaccess file via FTP I cannot seem to find the rule. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: It heavily depends on your configuration. In general, you may want to have separate Rewrite rules for each domain, so you'll have a finer control on who redirects and who does not. Or you can add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mydomain.com` between 1st and 2nd lines, this way your RewriteRule will not apply when HTTP_HOST is mydomain.com. However, I think separating rewrite rules for each domain may be easier for you to manage.